# Python object usage

Tags: python

How can I use the value of gcd in my add function. The current code is throwing error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/pythonclass", line 32, in <module>
    f4=f2+f3
  File "E:/python/pythonclass", line 22, in __add__
    common=gcd(newnum,newden)
NameError: global name 'gcd' is not defined
```

Code:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        self.num=top
        self.den=bottom
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
    def __gcd__(self,a,b):
       m=self.a
       n=self.b
       while m%n !=0:
          oldm=n
          oldn=n

          m=oldn
          n=oldm%oldn

       return n

    def __add__(self,f1):
        newnum =self.num*f1.den+self.den*f1.num
        newden= self.den*f1.den
        common=gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum,newden)



f2= Fraction(3,5)
print "First fraction" ,f2
f3= Fraction(5,3)
print "second fraction",f3

f4=f2+f3
print f4
```

Comment: There is no `gcd()` function in Python. You appear to expect the `__gcd__` method to be called; where did you get the impression it would?

Comment: And if that method did get called, it would ignore its arguments and use the instance attributes.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're talking about Python's `fractions` library and [its `gcd` method](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd), you encounter this error because you probably never imported `gcd`, but only `fractions` with `import fractions`.

   One way to solve that is to call `fractions.gcd` instead. The line:

   ```
   common=gcd(newnum,newden)
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   common=fractions.gcd(newnum,newden)
   ```

   Another way is to import `gcd`:

   ```
   from fractions import gcd
   ```
2. If you're talking not about Python's library, but your own `__gcd__` method (in which case, why are you reinventing the wheel instead of using Python's library?), I think this is obvious: you should be calling `self.__gcd__` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I would like to write fraction class not importing from library. I this class I am trying to write gcd class and ad method. in add method I want to use the output of gcd method. Can you help me to understand how can i use the output of gcd method overe here.

Comment: By calling `self.__gcd__` instead, so the line `common=gcd(newnum,newden)` becomes `common=self.__gcd__(newnum,newden)`.